# errorbars & colorbars python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, errorbar

I want to plot a scatter plot, that has a colorbar, and the data has errorbars. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)

x = np.linspace(0.1, 100, 10)
y = np.linspace(6, 18, 10)
yerr = np.random.random(10)
z = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

plt.scatter(x, y, s = 20, c = z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr = yerr, fmt = '.')
```

Here's the plot:
[image]

However, the errorbars are drawn in blue. I want to draw them according to the colorbar, how can I do this? For example, if a point has a value of `10` the errorbar should be drawn in `red`.

### EDIT

Following the answer suggested below, I wrote:

```
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet')
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(y), vmax=max(y))

plt.scatter(x, y, s = 20, c=z, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr = yerr, fmt = '.', c=cmap(norm(y)))
```

But still, it didn't work. Any suggestions?

I am still interested to get an answer to this question. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You can color your errorbars with a colormap, though you probably want to normalize the values you send it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

np.random.seed(123)

x = np.linspace(0.1, 100, 10)
y = np.linspace(6, 18, 10)
yerr = np.random.random(10)
z = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet')
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(y), vmax=max(y))

plt.scatter(x, y, s = 20, c=z, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr = yerr, fmt = '.', c=cmap(norm(y)))
```

Comment: `raise ValueError('to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "%s"\n%s' % (str(arg), exc))
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "[[ 0.          0.          0.5         1.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.99910873  1.        ]
 [ 0.30044276  1.          0.66729918  1.        ]
 [ 0.66729918  1.          0.30044276  1.        ]
 [ 1.          0.90123457  0.          1.        ]
 [ 1.          0.48002905  0.          1.        ]
 [ 0.99910873  0.07334786  0.          1.        ]
 [ 0.5         0.          0.          1.        ]]"
only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Comment: Hmm... what version of Matplotlib are you using?

Comment: The version is 1.1.1rc

Comment: If possible, you could try upgrading to at least 1.3. Otherwise, the third item returned from `plt.errorbar` is a list of the error bar line objects, and you could iterate over this list and set the color manually.

Comment: I got another error now: `ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "[[ ...]]" length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4`

Comment: Sounds like you're setting the color to your list of colors instead of a single color from that list.

Comment: I copied your exact code and tried to run it. It didn't work. Does it work on your laptop?